# C++ - Linking Error Using AMD Source Library

Tags: c++, sdk, gpu, fft, amd-processor

Hello Dearest Internet,

So, I've downloaded the clAmdFft library found [here](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-math-libraries/).

I've also went ahead  and done [this](http://code.google.com/p/a-dda/wiki/InstallingclAmdFft), (adding source files/libraries to compiler/system paths). Here they are after the fact:

```
echo $LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/lib:/opt/clAmdFft-1.10.321/lib64:/usr/lib:
echo $C_INCLUDE_PATH
/opt/clAmdFft-1.10.321/include:
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/opt/clAmdFft-1.10.321/lib64:/opt/clAmdFft-1.10.321/lib32:/usr/lib:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/lib::/opt/clAmdFft-1.10.321
```

Here is the top of one of the .cpp files that I would like to use this library in:

```
// AMD APPML FFT
#include <clAmdFft.h>
// IVE TRIED THESE TOO
//#include "clAmdFft.h"
//#include <clAmdFft>
```

And finally, here is my sugar sweet Makefile, (nothing real complicated here, I've done it like this consistently before)

```
#
#
#  Compile Super Mega Awesome Program For Winners
#
#
#

# -std=c++0x is required for using <chrono>

objects =  L1.o L2.o L3.o 
sharedObjects = SL1.so
exec = SL1
GCC=gcc
GPP=g++
CFLAGS= -I /usr/local/cuda/include -g
LDFLAGS = -L /usr/lib -lOpenCL

# This apparently addresses linking problems w/ clAmdFft & NVIDIA drivers
LDFLAGS += -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs

SL1: 
        $(GPP) $(CFLAGS) -o L1.o -c -std=c++0x -fPIC main.cpp       
        $(GPP) $(CFLAGS) -o L2.o -c -fPIC L2.cpp
        $(GPP) $(CFLAGS) -o L3.o -c -fPIC L3.cpp
        $(GPP) $(CFLAGS) -Wall -shared  -o $(sharedObjects) $(objects)
        $(GPP) $(sharedObjects) -o $(exec) -g $(LDFLAGS)

.PHONY : clean
clean: 
        rm $(objects) $(sharedObjects) $(exec)




#EOF
```

Why then, dear Internet, do I get the following error?

```
L3.cpp:24:22: fatal error: clAmdFft.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I mean this seems very straightforward. After a quick perusal of this site as well as google in general, I can't seem to find a solid answer as to why this isn't working right meow.  Hope you guys can help! Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest that you need `-I /opt/clAmdFft-1.10.321/include` added to your `CFLAGS= -I /usr/local/cuda/include -g` line.

Comment: Oh boy that DEFINITELY did it, (at least, it compiled, we'll see about the actual instantiation :P), THANK YOU.

Can I ask why that is needed if I added that to C_INCLUDE_PATH? Is that not the global include path for additional source/headers/libraries? Like, let's say I want to use one THOUSAND different 3rd party libraries, for fun. Is there a way just have 1000 #include statements and a configuration for the global system linking where gcc/g++ knows where it is already?

Thank you Mats Petersson. You should answer the question w/ an answer so that I can upvote your answer : )

Comment: I have added an answer, and also covering the "C_INCLUDE_PATH" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comment, adding the `-I /opt/clAmdFft-1.10.321/include` to the `CFLAGS= -I /usr/local/cuda/include -g` is my preferred way to solve this particular problem.

As to how to use `C_INCLUDE_PATH`, technically your usage is correct - except you are not compiling the code with `gcc` but with `g++` and thus you should use `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`.

Here's a compile-example (not showing my xemacs session creating testing.cpp and testing.h -  testing.cpp simply doing `#include <testing.h>` (which contains a simple define that I'm printing).

```
$ mkdir ../testing
$ export C_INCLUDE_PATH=../testing
$ g++ -Wall testing.cpp
testing.cpp:2:21: fatal error: testing.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
$ export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=../testing
$ g++ -Wall testing.cpp
```

However, the whole point of using makefiles is that they define what you get included from where. Using global environment variables will just lead to your project depending on what each user on the system has configured their `C_INCLUDE_PATH` and `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`.

Likewise, if you end up moving your project from one machine to another, if all the include-paths, etc, are in the makefile, you can just copy the project files [and install the dependencies, of course - although you CAN have the makefile do that too, if you work at it]. If you rely on `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` and the like, you end up having to also go edit your .bashrc or whatever.

(And I learned something new today, I didn't even know these environment variables existed).

Comment: Damn, not enough REP for upvote. You sir are an American (Swedish?) Hero. I knew about C_INCLUDE_PATH but NOT CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH. GORGEOUS response.